# Rewrite Query String

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have this URL:

```
oldsite.com/profile.php?uid=10
```

I would like to rewrite it to:

```
newsite.com/utenti/10
```

How can I do that?

I wrote this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^uid=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^profile\.php$ http://www.newsite.com/utenti/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But $1 match the full query string and not just the user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$1" matches the first pair of brackets on the same line (the RewriteRule); you need "%1", which matches the first pair of brackets on the /previous/ line - the RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^uid=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^profile\.php$ http://www.newsite.com/utenti/%1 [R=301,L]
```

A better way would be to do it with only 1 line (a RewriteRule), but you can't do that if the uid is in the QueryString.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^oldsite.com$
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} uid=([0-9]+)
        RewriteRule ^/profile\.php http://newsite.com/utenti/%1 [NC,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

the point is to use %1, not $1